# AnimationEnd not working

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I am using `AnimationEnd` to trigger adding a new class. It works fine in Chrome but the other browsers are not responding. I am not sure why.

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.background-image').on('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd animationEnd', function() {
            $(this).addClass('visible');
        });
    });

</script>
```

CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade-in {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fade-in {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fade-in {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fade-in {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

.background-image {
  background: url('images/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;

  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;

  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-animation-name: fade-in;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;

  -moz-animation-name: fade-in;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
}

.background-image.visible {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like it was tripping over mozAnimationEnd. Try this, I tested it in Firefox:

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/7U9Hj/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.background-image').on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function() {
        $(this).addClass('visible');
    });
});
```

Comment: Also - IE 10 is NOT using the MS prefixes for CSS3. They are using the standard names without prefix. Just a heads up

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp Thanks I forgot about that, MS is always a painful after thought...