# CSS3 Keyframe animation working in chrome, not firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a key frame animation that I animate on hover for a navigation menu. When I hover over, the animation works just fine but I want it to finish the animation if I move the mouse off. This function is working correctly in Chrome, but not Firefox and I can't figure out why.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u95Lumm3/1/

One thing I have noticed, on FF the animation resets even if you keep the mouse on top.

Simply removing 'mozAnimationEnd' does not fix the issue like it does in a different, but similar, question on Stackoverflow.

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: green;">
    <div class="nav-bnt">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$('.nav-bnt').bind('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
    $('.nav-bnt').removeClass("animation");
});

$('.nav-bnt').hover(function(){
  $('.nav-bnt').addClass("animation");        
})
```

CSS:

```
.nav-bnt div, .nav-bnt div:nth-of-type(3) {
    top: -15px; bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    margin: auto;

    -moz-transform: translate3d(-1px, 0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-1px, 0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: translate3d(-1px, 0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-1px, 0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
}

.nav-bnt div:nth-of-type(2) {
    top: 0;
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-1px, 0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-1px, 0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: translate3d(-1px, 0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-1px, 0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
}

.nav-bnt div:nth-of-type(3) {
    top: 0;
    bottom: -16px;
}


.animation div:nth-of-type(2) {
    -webkit-animation: navanimateleft .5s;
    -moz-animation: navanimateleft .5s;
    -o-animation: navanimateleft .5s;
    -ms-animation: navanimateleft .5s;  
    animation: navanimateleft .5s;  
}

.animation div:nth-of-type(1), .animation div:nth-of-type(3) {

    -webkit-animation: navanimateright .5s;
    -moz-animation: navanimateright .5s;
    -ms-animation: navanimateright .5s;
    -o-animation: navanimateright .5s;
    animation: navanimateright .5s;

}

@-webkit-keyframes navanimateleft {
    0%      {-webkit-transform: translate3d(-1px, 0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);}
    30%     {-webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);}
    60%     {-webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0px, 0px) rotate(180deg);}
    100%    {-webkit-transform: translate3d(-1px, 0px, 0px) rotate(180deg);}  
}

@keyframes navanimateleft {
    0%      {transform: translate3d(-1px, 0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);}
    30%     {transform: translate3d(-10px, 0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);}
    60%     {transform: translate3d(-10px, 0px, 0px) rotate(180deg);}
    100%    {transform: translate3d(-1px, 0px, 0px) rotate(180deg);}  
}


@-webkit-keyframes navanimateright {
    0%      {-webkit-transform: translate3d(-1px, 0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);}
    30%     {-webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);}
    60%     {-webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0px, 0px) rotate(180deg);}
    100%    {-webkit-transform: translate3d(-1px, 0px, 0px) rotate(180deg);}  
}


@keyframes navanimateright {
    0%      {transform: translate3d(-1px, 0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);}
    30%     {transform: translate3d(10px, 0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);}
    60%     {transform: translate3d(10px, 0px, 0px) rotate(180deg);}
    100%    {transform: translate3d(-1px, 0px, 0px) rotate(180deg);}  
}


.nav-bnt {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    z-index: 999;
    transition: all 0.25s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s linear;
} 

.nav-bnt:hover {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.10);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.10);
    -o-transform: scale(1.10);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.10);
    transform: scale(1.10);
}


.nav-bnt div {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #993399;
    height: 3px;
    width: 15px;
    position: absolute;

    transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AnimationEnd not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553344/animationend-not-working)

Comment: the 'mozAnimationEnd' isn't tripping the animation up. I've removed it and still happens. http://jsfiddle.net/u95Lumm3/2/

Comment: Works in FF 38 (beta). Open console and double check you don't get the "removed" message: http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/u95Lumm3/3/

Comment: Looks like the `:hover` state for the button might be interfering with it.

Comment: Actually, while that did help, I found the real issue and posted an answer. Transitions overwrite the animation properties in firefox so that was causing the strange animation reset and the 'animationend' property from not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transition property overwrites the animation property in Firefox. [This post helped me find the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158301/firefox-resets-animation-on-hover)

Removing

```
.nav-bnt div {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #993399;
    height: 3px;
    width: 15px;
    position: absolute;

    transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
```

Becomes

```
.nav-bnt div {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #993399;
    height: 3px;
    width: 15px;
    position: absolute;

}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u95Lumm3/5/

Comment: And apparently I can't accept my own answer for two days >.>